# React-Native Axios Request & Undefined props

Tags: json, react-native, axios

I'm using Axios to do poll a web api to return some things. At present, Axios will run the API, and I can log that the correct response has been returned as it console.log says:

```
(2) [Object, Object]
```

However, If I try to do

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: "Results",
    component: "SearchResults",
    passProps: {response: response}
  });
```

I get a "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined at eval*" and gives me the error occurring at the line that contains *this.props.navigator.push*.

Related code:

```
_axiosFetch(searchString) {
    var queryURL = 'http://mourningafter.eu/DataService.php?state=get&name=' + searchString
    axios.get(queryURL)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response)
          this.props.navigator.push({
               title: "Results",
               component: SearchResults,
               passProps: {response: response}
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        });
}
```

I'm confused to say the least!

any help would be great, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what is the context of `_axiosFetch` call, but let's assume it references your component. Then, focus on `.then(function(response){})` callback - it changes context and no longer references component, thus, you cannot call `this.props...` in callback.

Use arrow function to bind context into callback function

```
_axiosFetch(searchString) {
    var queryURL = 'http://mourningafter.eu/DataService.php?state=get&name=' + searchString
    axios.get(queryURL)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          this.props.navigator.push({
               title: "Results",
               component: SearchResults,
               passProps: {response: response}
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        });
}
```